# Quantity discount in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have got a table with the following structure:

`id - int
from - float 1 dec(km's)
till - float 1 dec(km's)
price float 2 dec`

with the values

```
(1, 0, 9.9, 15),
(2, 10, 19.9, 11),
(3, 20, 24.9, 7)
```

What I need is a calculation of the price summed up

So let's say you travel 23 km
Your first 9.9 km's will be 15eu/km
Your 10-19.9 km will be 11eu/km
Your final km's will be 7eu/km

Because I don't know how much rows this table will hold, how can I make a function or SP, that resolves the price for me?

The price will be:
(9.9 - 0) * 15 +
(19.9 - 10) * 11 +
(3.2 * 7)

Comment: Please elaborate in the question on what inputs look like and what results you want to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query in order to calculate the total price for a predefined number of kms:

```
DECLARE @km INT = 23

SELECT SUM(IIF([to] < @km, [to] - [from], @km - [from]) * price)
FROM mytable
WHERE [from] <= @km
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11367/1)

**Explanation:**

The following query:

```
DECLARE @km INT = 23

SELECT IIF([to] < @km, [to] - [from], @km - [from]) AS km,  price
FROM #mytable
WHERE [from] <= @km
```

produces the following output:

```
km  price
=========
9,9 15
9,9 11
3   7
```

Comment: What if OP uses SQL Server 2008? Note that `IIF` is `SQL Server 2012+`

Comment: Thank you Giorgos for the answer, I did not knew this was possible, you helped me a lot! Now I don't have to solve this in my application layer :)